# Can somebody tell me where i do mistake in this query? I am working with SSMS latest version

Tags: sql-server, common-table-expression

```
With PopVsVac ( Continent, Location, Date, Population, New_Vaccinations, RollingPeopleVaccinated )
AS
(
    SELECT
        dea.continent,
        dea.location,
        dea.date,
        dea.population,
        vac.new_vaccinations,
        SUM( CAST( vac.new_vaccinations AS int ) ) OVER ( PARTITION BY dea.location ORDER BY dea.location, dea.date ) AS RollingPeopleVaccinated
FROM
    covidDeaths dea
    JOIN covidVaccinations vac ON
        dea.location = vac.location
        AND
        dea.date = vac.date
WHERE
    dea.continent IS NOT NULL
)
```

Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 81
Incorrect syntax near ')'.

just correct my mistake pls

Comment: A `WITH` CTE is not directly executable: you **must** have a _final_ `SELECT` query (or DML) immediately after the closing `)` of the `WITH` part.

Comment: Add SELECT * FROM PopVsVac  at the very end

Comment: Also, you don't need to repeat column-names in the `WITH PopVsVac ( colNames )` part.

Comment: `dea.continent IS NOT NULL` <-- I'd like to know why `continent` is a nullable column...

Comment: This question has nothing to do with MySQL or SQLite. Please remove those irrelevant tags.

Comment: FYI the version of SSMS isn't relevant because thats just a UI, you need to provide the result of `select @@version` (because latest version today will not be latest version when read in a years time).

Answer (score 1):

You have two main issues:

- You are missing a final select after the `WITH`
- There is no `CAST` as int in MYSQL (maybe this is no real issue, but just incorrect tags in your question)

Furthermore, SQL key words should never be used as table name or column name, so it's highly recommended to replace your two column names "date" with other names.

Changing all these things allows to execute your query, see here for MYSQL: [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/XjT-9HSJ)

And here for SQLServer: [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/XrPgwOS3)

Comment: Thanks Guys, SELECT  just after the closing parenthesis ) done the work , and thanks for your suggestions.